# Saving Processing result to GeoJSON string instead of QgsVectorLayer or GeoJSON file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I run `processing.run("native:buffer")` and from newly created vector I get all features and export them to string using `QgsJsonExporter()`.

My problem is that newly created vector gives new IDs to all features and they aren't equal to attribute ID's values. And after exporting them to GeoJSON using `QgsJsonExporter()` I get GeoJSON features with identifiers.

However I can solve this by declaring `processing.run("native:buffer")` algorithm OUTPUT to .geosjon file and opening it afterwards.

Is there a way that I can get GeoJSON string without IDs without having to save OUTPUT to .geojson and reading it to string afterwards.

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer(sys.argv[1],"mygeojson","ogr")

def runProcessingNativeBuffer(inputGeoJson, distance):
    processing.algorithmHelp("native:buffer")
    return processing.run("native:buffer",
                         {'INPUT': inputGeoJson,
                          'DISTANCE': distance, 'SEGMENTS': 5,
                          'END_CAP_STYLE': 0, 'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                          'MITER_LIMIT': 2, 'DISSOLVE': False,
                          'OUTPUT': "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"})

ats = runProcessingNativeBuffer(vl, sys.argv[2])

vl1=ats['OUTPUT']

features = vl1.getFeatures()
exporter = QgsJsonExporter()
print("GEOJSON",exporter.exportFeatures(features))
```

IDs in properties are fine I don't need additional IDs in `"features"`

[image: IDs in "properties" are fine I don't need additional IDs in "features"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No chance to export features without `id` unless you manually remove it from dictionary using some code. But using [`exportFeature`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsJsonExporter.html?highlight=qgsjsonexporter#qgis.core.QgsJsonExporter.exportFeature) instead of `exportFeatures`, you can assign `id` value in properties to upper `id` like this:

```
{
  "features":[
     { "geometry": { ... },
       "id": 25,
       "properties": { "id": 25,
                        ...
```

Sample script:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

exporter = QgsJsonExporter()

### Lines you need ###
json_string = '{"features":['

# set id parameter to f["id"]. id is paramater and "id" is the field name in attribute table
json_string += ','.join([exporter.exportFeature(f, id=f["id"]) for f in features])
json_string += '], "type": "FeatureCollection"} ' 
######################

print(json_string)
```

Sample result:

```json
{
    "features": [{
        "geometry": { ... },
        "id": 20,
        "properties": {
            "id": 20,
            "namas": "foo"
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    }, {
        "geometry": { ... },
        "id": 25,
        "properties": {
            "id": 25,
            "namas": "bar"
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    }],
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

Comment: The result is string. I changed its format to make it look more beautiful.